# Is multiseat possible on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, multiseat

I want to setup a multiseat configuration on my Windows 8 PC but the only software I can find that creates a multiseat setup is SoftXPand but their site says it only supports up to Windows 7 and after trying to install it on Windows 8 my pc would not boot properly anymore and I had to refresh the Windows installation.

Comment: You will have to find an alternative to SoftXPand.  On a related note you might clarify what you want to do exactly.  As far as I known the only versions of Windows that supports a multiseat configuration is Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a special Server Version called [Windows MultiPoint Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_MultiPoint_Server) which does what you want.

> Windows MultiPoint Server is a Microsoft Windows Server-based
>   operating system using Remote Desktop Services technology **to host
>   multiple simultaneous independent computing stations or terminals
>   connected to a single computer.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a product called BoxedVDI from [Listeq](http://www.listeq.com/) which runs in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Aster](http://www.ibik.ru/downloads-free-trial) in win 8.1 64bit works fine,

there are another solution [BeTwin ES](http://www.thinsoftinc.com/download_selection.aspx) .